# Flagging old abandoned questions

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

I've been searching Meta for a similar question or an answer to this, but I couldn't find it.

I really like things to be clean and organized. When going through old questions (6 month or more), I'm coming across a lot of questions that are clearly abandoned by the OP (see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816662/hp-loadrunner-ssl-protocol-error) for example).

Now these are valid, interesting, good questions, **but** - are lacking some answers from the OP, which were asked by users in the comments section. Problem is that the OP is not answering, probably because the question was self solved.

As I said - I really like things to be clean and organized, and these questions, for my opinion, are just abandoned junk lying around.

In order to keep Stack Overflow clean, are we supposed to flag these kind of question? If yes - under which reason?

Comment: Any question that does not present enough information to afford a (relatively) concise answer is *not* a good question for our purposes, no matter how interesting it is, or its *potential* for being a good question in the event that more information were provided.  I'm not sure what measure of "valid[ity]" would apply to such a question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The fact that the question is "abandoned" is completely irrelevant.  Likewise the age of the question is not really a factor.

If the question (any question, old or new, active or abandoned) is not answerable without more information from the OP, then the appropriate course of action is to vote to close (or flag to close if you have <3K rep).  The most appropriate reason is usually "Unclear what you're asking" in this cases where more info is needed, but "Too broad" is also applicable in some cases.

> [image]

But if the question is answerable by someone who has the right knowledge and/or experience, then there is nothing to do.  Leave it alone and someone hopefully will come along and provide the answer.  Granted the OP may not be around to accept it, but other users may upvote it if they find it helpful.  And the answer could then help others who may have the same issue in the future.

The key point is it isn't the age of the question or the activity-level of the original asker, it is the value to other programmers.  If the question is good, focused, and contains enough information to provide a complete answer, then leave it alone.  If it doesn't then vote to close it.

Answer (score 15):

There is no need, if question is bad downvote/flag it, it will be handled by community user in 30 days otherwise leave it.

From [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba):

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "dead" questions (RemoveDeadQuestions, RemoveMigrationStubs in the case of a migration or RemoveRejectedMigrations in the case of a rejected migration).

or

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments ... it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned" questions (RemoveAbandonedQuestions).

Comment: I wrote a user-script which will display the question's status wrt. being Roomba'ed: [Roomba Forecaster - When will the question be Rooma'ed? If it won't, why?](http://stackapps.com/q/7239)