# In triage, is it OK to take the age of the question into account?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm new to triage. Sometimes I see a question which is really bad - badly written, no code provided or too much code, formatting problems, vague "help me" formulation. This question definitely doesn't deserve to stay on the site as it is - it could easily fit into "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking". Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067856/how-to-run-pl-sql-cursor-in-shell-script

Should I take the age of the question into account?

My argument is that a new user with a new question could probably be encouraged to fix these serious problems. On the other hand, if it's a day old and unfixed, I don't want to leave it hanging around.

But, I may not understand how triage works, so maybe this should not be a consideration.

Comment: The way you encourage people to improve posts is by down voting and close voting (little less so with down voting).  Doesn't matter how old it is.

Comment: My answer in [Flagging old abandoned questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345229/flagging-old-abandoned-questions/345231#345231) is very relevant to this situation as well

Comment: You're reviewing _now_ and the _current_ version of the post. Don't assume what might will become of that post later. So if it is bad, then flag for closure and downvote.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this question is a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345229/flagging-old-abandoned-questions

Comment: @dash2 not really.  I think the accepted answer is generally the same, but the questions are different enough that I wouldn't flag it as a duplicate

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue Most notably, *Do not choose "Requires Editing" if you know the question cannot be made answerable without clarification or additions from its author.* So it doesn't really matter if a new user could theoretically be persuaded to fix the issues. If they're the *only* one who could fix it, it's Unsalvageable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sole reason for Triage's existence is *fast* handling of questions as they come in. If you're not going to ruthlessly judge questions as they presently are, don't bother reviewing in Triage. Triage is entirely about rapid, reasonably accurate bucketing of questions, and if a question was asked poorly, too bad! The sooner the author gets feedback on it, the sooner they have a chance to fix it, and more importantly, the fewer answerers will waste time looking at a question that's not workable.